# How does a packet destined for OpenVPN go through iptables?

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, iptables

I have been interested in this question for a long time.  I have an OpenVPN server configured, I followed the logs, and did not quite understand the route of packets from the client to the VPN server. I have not found anywhere on the Internet a good explanation about this, so I will ask here, and I will hope for your help, it is very important for me to understand it well.

With the OpenVPN server and client configured (tun), everything works fine for me, all client traffic passes through the VPN tunnel.

But I'm interested in one thing.
If I understood correctly, then the traffic on the client is encapsulated in another packet (tunneling), and sent to the OpenVPN server? When this packet arrives on the server, where does it go next, if we are talking about iptables?
It passes through the PREROUTING chain, and should go to the FORWARD chain, but from where does the kernel know that it needs to be sent to the FORWARD chain? After all, the packet is encapsulated and has the destination address of the OpenVPN server and not the original address. First you need to encrypt this packet somewhere? And only then send it to the FORWARD chain, right? Or am I wrong?

Can someone explain how the packet intended for the OpenVPN server from the client passes through iptables, and how does he understand that this traffic needs to be sent via FORWARD? I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: There are two ways to do it. If you make use of the `client-to-client` internal approach, the forward filtering won't apply. However, it's also possible to do it with the "generic" IP forwarding approach, in which cases the filtering will apply.

Comment: @Tom Yan thanks for the answer. But I don't quite understand what kind of filtering are you talking about? :D How, with the help of such filtering, the kernel knows that this packet needs to be sent to FORWARD ?

Comment: @TomYan , Also, I do not have "client-to-client" in my server conf file

Comment: filtering refers to "being processed by the firewall", i.e. go through "FORWARD"; with that said, in the client-to-client case, encapsulated traffics are still governed by INPUT/OUTPUT, regardless of whether the are being forwarded by the IP stack of the OS or internally by OpenVPN.

Comment: Actually I missed the fact that you might be talking about the scenario where the traffics are to be forwarded to hosts other than the clients of the same VPN. In that case client-to-client does not apply, and such traffics can only be forwarded by the IP stack (for obvious reason).

Comment: You can think of it like this: OpenVPN the program is a bit like a managed switch, with client-to-client clients are allowed to talk to each other through it without involving (from the "virtual" perspective) a router (the server host), but they can also talk to hosts in other networks through / other clients by involving the "router". Whenever it's handled by the "router", the traffics being forwarded will go through the FORWARD chain.

Comment: @TomYan , Thank you very much for such a detailed answer. I am interested in the part where the encapsulated traffic comes to the host, and then in the server logs I see how it passes through the FORWARD chain, with the source address 10.8.0.0/24. I am describing a case when a client visited a website. Where does the packet "open" after passing the PREROUTING chain? Or should the package go to INPUT and from there to FORWARD?

Comment: @TomYan , For example, an OpenVPN client visited a website with the IP address 8.8.8.8. Client pub ip= 1.2.3.4, client virtual ip= 10.8.0.6. OpenVPN IP= 1.1.1.1 The client's OpenVPN program did the following:
Original packet:
src=1.2.3.4
dst=8.8.8.8
The packet is encapsulated:
src=1.2.3.4
dst=1.1.1.1
Am I right?
Then the package will come to the server with src=1.2.3.4, dst=1.1.1.1 (current host)
How then did the packеt end up in the FORWARD chain with src=10.8.0.6, dst=8.8.8.8 ?

Comment: @TomYan , the packet must first be decrypted. And only then the server will understand where to redirect it?

Comment: `Or should the package go to INPUT and from there to FORWARD?` It does NOT work that way at all. `The packet is encapsulated: src=1.2.3.4 dst=1.1.1.1 Am I right? Then the package will come to the server with src=1.2.3.4, dst=1.1.1.1` while this is correct. You have to understand that it does NOT work like NAT though. The virtualized network is on a total different "layer" (I don't mean like OSI layer though).

Comment: The key concept is, before an actual packet entered / after it "escaped" from the tunnel interface, that's one "story", which is purely handled by the IP stack of the OS and the process / pipeline has nothing to do with those of the other "story" when it comes to the firewall. The other "story" is after it entered / until it escaped from the tunnel interface. This part is just like any other program sending / receiving traffics from another host.

Comment: `Where does the packet "open"` in the OpenVPN program; `the packet must first be decrypted. And only then the server will understand where to redirect it?` I think so. I only know for sure that, with client-to-client traffics for another client does NOT escape from (and re-enter) the tunnel interface but are directly/internally forwarded. I'm not entirely sure whether they actually needs to be decrypted and re-encrypted in that case, but certainly for traffics that need to escape from the tunnel interface, decryption must occur before that.

Comment: Btw by "enter" the tunnel interface I mean like "goes out through" it. And for "layer" I should probably have used "scope" or "context" instead.

Comment: @TomYan , Thanks a lot for your help. I appreciate it, although I still don't fully understand how it works :)